# I can't get this SQL to work, can anyone spot it?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

```
SELECT 
    [Stock Conversion Items].SCID, 
    [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC], 
    [Stock Conversion Items].[Quantity], 
    [Stock Conversion].[Date], 
    [products/stock].[Description] 
FROM 
    [Stock Conversion Items] 
INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion] 
    ON [Stock Conversion Items].SCID = [Stock Conversion].SCID 
INNER JOIN [products/stock] 
    ON [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC] = [products/stock].[Product Code] 
ORDER BY [Stock Conversion Items].SCID;
```

This code is pretty self explanatory, basically I get a syntax operator error that I can't solve at all.

Comment: Looks more or less OK (besides having the space and slash in table names, brrr). What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Those are some of the most awful names used for a database column evah.

Comment: @SWeko I've seen worse.  Although I don't agree with [products/stock] as a table name

Comment: This is a fairly basic query, I suggest re-creating it with the query designer so that Access can satisfy itself with all it's mis-guided parenthesis ^_^

Comment: I tried that, it still seemed to find errors....Also, the table names aren't mine, i've been given the db to adapt to fit a new style of business, Camel Caps everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reformated the query a bit, and got it looking like this:

```
SELECT sci.SCID, sci.[Result PC], sci.Quantity, sci.Date, s.Description
FROM [Stock Conversion Items] sci
INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion] sc 
   ON sci.SCID = sc.SCID 
INNER JOIN [products/stock] s 
   ON sci.[Result PC] = s.[Product Code] 
ORDER BY sci.SCID;
```

The only thing that can fail in that statement are the `on` clauses. Are you sure that both SCID columns are of the same type, as well as the [Result PC] and [Product Code] columns?

Comment: One of the SCID values is Autonumber, the other is number?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Access seems to want to put parenthesis around the first join.  This seems to work:

```
SELECT [Stock Conversion Items].SCID, [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC], [Stock Conversion Items].Quantity, [Stock Conversion].Date, [products/stock].Description
FROM ([Stock Conversion] INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] ON [Stock Conversion].SCID = [Stock Conversion Items].SCID) INNER JOIN [products/stock] ON [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC] = [products/stock].[Product Code];
```

Comment: Tried this, I just get type mismatch in expression

Comment: Make sure the fields you are joining on are all of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT [Stock Conversion Items].SCID,
     [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC],
     [Stock Conversion Items].Quantity,
     [products/stock].Description,
     [Stock Conversion].[SC Date],
     [Stock Conversion].[Created By]

     FROM [Stock Conversion Items]
      INNER JOIN ([products/stock] INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion]
        ON [products/stock].[Product Code] = [Stock Conversion].[Source PC])
        ON [Stock Conversion Items].SCID = [Stock Conversion].SCID;
```

So this is what Access has come up with to solve my problem, managed to get the thing working, think it may of been a data type mismatch. So thanks Sweko.